# Why won't my ASP.Net Core Web API Controller return XML?

Tags: xml, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have the following simple Web API controller:

```
    // GET: api/customers
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
        {
        var customers = await uow.Users.GetAllAsync();
        var dto = customers.Select(p => new CustomerDto {Id = p.Id, Email = p.Email, UserName = p.UserName});
        return Ok(dto); // IEnumerable<CustomerDto>
        }
```

In Postman, I'm setting the Accept header to `application/xml`, but no matter what I try, I can only get JSON data back.

[image: Postman screen shot]

I read somewhere that in order to get XML, I must add `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` attributes to my DTO, which now looks like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class CustomerDto
    {
    [DataMember]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    [DataMember]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Login Name")]
    [DataMember]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    }
```

I've been at it several hours now and I'm just not seeing why it doesn't work. I've tried:

- Making the action method synchronous and asynchronous
- Returning the data directly, and setting the return type to `IEnumerable<CustomerDto>`
- Converting the collection to an array instead of a list
- Returning an `IActionResult`
- Returning a single item, instead of a collection
- I've verified that the Accept header is showing up in the request by examining it in the debugger.
- Lots of "Googling with Bing" and reading various blogs
- Creating a new WebAPI project from the template and seeing if there is any inspiration there (not really).

  I expect it's simple, but I can't see it...

Comment: Could you show you registered your Xml formatters in Startup.cs?

Comment: Have you ever configured formatters?

Comment: Of course that was the problem. Last time I used a WebAPI that was all enabled by default. I forgot about the new lightweight pay-as-you-go approach in ASP.Net 5! The extension methods were not really very discoverable, though, either. I had to know to install another NuGet package then dot into the AddMvc() call.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Xml formatters are part of a separate package: `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml`

Add the above package and update your startup.cs like below:

```
services
    .AddMvc()
    .AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters();
```

OR

```
services
    .AddMvc()
    .AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
```

Comment: Ahh... I wondered if it might be something like that. Shame the documentation is a bit unfinished. Wasn't the XML formatter enabled by default in MVC5?

Comment: Yes it was in MVC5 but this was changed very early on in ASP.NET 5

Comment: I see you've edited your answer to present the two formatters as alternatives rather than to be used together. Is that correct? If so, what are the pros and cons of each formatter?

Comment: @TimLong: You would have to look for that information in MSDN probably.

Comment: These methods don't seem to exist with the latest version of asp.net core!

Comment: In mvc 1.1 I needed: `services.AddMvc(options => {options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;}).AddXmlSerializerFormatters().AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters();` or it would always give me json

Comment: I concur with @emirhosseini in that neither of the two are present in the .NET Core 1.1 and Adding the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml  does not seem to make them available either.

Comment: After reading all answers , Its just says how much Microsoft is creating confusion by changing method names.

Comment: This answer is fine but be wary, your data objects must also include a parameterless constructor or it seems it will still return only JSON. See Roolingen's answer for some details https://stackoverflow.com/a/53007279/368318

Answer (score 20):

For Asp.Net Core 2.x you basically need these 3 things in order to ***return*** an XML response:

*Startup.cs:*

```
services
    .AddMvcCore(options => options.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerOutputFormatter())
```

*CustomerController.cs:*

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class CustomerController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            var customer = new CustomerDto {Id = 1, Name = "John", Age = 45};
            return Ok(customer);
        }
    }
}
```

*CustomerDto.cs:*

```
namespace WebApplication
{
    public class CustomerDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And then upon adding the Accept "application/xml" header to the request an XML formatted result will be returned.

A very **important note** that I had to find out for myself is if your model does not have an implicit of explicit parameterless constructor then the response will be written as a json. Given the following example

```
namespace WebApplication
{
    public class CustomerDto
    {
        public CustomerDto(int id, string name, int age)
        {
            Id = id;
            Name = name;
            Age = age;
        }

         public int Id { get; }
         public string Name { get; }
         public int Age { get; }
    }
}
```

It would return **json**. To this model you should add

```
public CustomerDto()
{
}
```

And that would again return **XML**.

Comment: +1 for the parameterless constructor point, without that someone would spend hours scratching his head wondering what's going on !

Comment: Isn't this based on the `Accept` header that's provided.. I'm pretty sure that's how the API worked..

Comment: Regarding the parameterless constructor: this is also true when returning an anonymous object. When you do it will always return JSON!

Comment: Regarding the parameterless constructor, this applies to any nested objects as well.  There must be parameterless constructors all the way down or it will return JSON.

Answer (score 7):

The following solution worked for me nicely.

At `Startup.cs`

```
services.AddMvc()
       .AddXmlSerializerFormatters()
       .AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters();
```

At `YourController.cs`

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Get")]
    [Produces("application/xml")] // If you don't like to send Content-Type header
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        try
        {                
            var user = _userManager.FindByNameAsync('user').Result;
            if (user != null)
            {
                if (!_userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, 'password').Result)
                {
                    return Unauthorized();
                }
                else
                {
                    var result = _services.GetDataFromService(Convert.ToInt64(2), start_date, end_date);
                    return Ok(result);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return Unauthorized();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Unauthorized();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

For **MVC 1.1** you need to add the Package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml` and edit your *Startup.cs*:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc(options => { options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true; })
        .AddXmlSerializerFormatters()
        .AddXmlDataContractSeria‌​lizerFormatters();
}
```

Now you can set the Accept Header:

XML: `application/xml`

JSON: `application/json`

Answer (score 6):

For *asp.net core 2.x*, you can configure **OutputFormatter**.

you can try following code pieces in startup.cs class ConfigureServices method.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.AddMvc(action =>
     {
         action.ReturnHttpNotAcceptable = true;
         action.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlDataContractSerializerOutputFormatter());
     });

     //...
}
```

For using **XmlDataContractSerializerOutputFormatter**  references from *Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters* package from nuget.

now it should work for *xml* and *json*

Answer (score 2):

For .net core 3.x , you can use like below

```
services.AddControllers(options=> {
            options.OutputFormatters.RemoveType(typeof(SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter));
            options.InputFormatters.RemoveType(typeof(SystemTextJsonInputFormatter));
            options.ReturnHttpNotAcceptable = true;
        }).AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
```

Answer (score 0):

For Core 2.x versions, the only thing that you need to do is to have the following code inside the **ConfigureServie method** of **Startup.cs** file.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc()
            .AddMvcOptions(o => o.OutputFormatters.Add(
              new XmlDataContractSerializerOutputFormatter()));
}
```

You need to reference the **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters**.

Answer (score 0):

For Core 2.x versions, you have to do two things. First thing is you need to add following code inside the ConfigureServices method of Startup.cs file.

```
services.AddMvc()
.AddMvcOptions(o => o.OutputFormatters.Add(
    new XmlDataContractSerializerOutputFormatter())
);
```

And then add the Accept "application/xml" header to the request as below on Postman. Then XML formatted result will be returned.

[image]