# Produces data annotation not working for xml in asp.net core 2.1

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-core

I'm using `[Produces("application/xml")]` data annotation to return my response in `XML` but unfortunately it do not return any thing. When I remove `[Produces]` data annotation it returns me data in JSON format. I've also added `AddXmlSerializerFormatters()` formatter.

Here is my controller action

```
[HttpGet("Generate")]
[Produces("application/xml")]
public XDocument Get()
{
    XDocument sitemap = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "yes"),
             new XElement("urlset", XNamespace.Get("http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"),
                  from item in business
                  select CreateItemElement(item)
                  )
             );

        return Ok(sitemap.ToString());
}
```

Here is my ConfigureService method in startup class

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.AddMvc().AddXmlSerializerFormatters()
     .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

     services.AddDbContext<ListingDbContext>
            (options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("App4Rental_Website_DB")));
      services.AddTransient<IRentalRepository, RentalRepository>();
      services.AddTransient<IScrapingRepository, ScrapingRepository>();
}
```

Its working fine JSON result but not working for XML. I'm unable to understand problem.

Comment: Have you had a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38316358/why-wont-my-asp-net-core-web-api-controller-return-xml) maybe it can be of some help

Comment: @lzzy Yes, I've followed this too. But still not working.

Comment: which accept header are you sending? aspnet will return the requested format, so you need to request XML the get XML

Comment: @cyptus I'm sending application/xml

Comment: What is the content in `Get()`? Check the debug output window to see whether there is any error? What is the reason you need to return `XDocument`?

Comment: @TaoZhou, Yes I've checked. There is no error. It returns JSON successfully when I remove 'Produces' data annotation. Actually I'm creating sitemap so thats way I'm returning XDocument.

Comment: The client must explicitly request the content format. See [Content Negotiation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-2.2#content-negotiation)

Comment: Use `XNamespace.Get("http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9") + "urlset"` to add namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `XDocument`, it should not be serialized to xml format.

In general, we return Object like `Product` with xml formatter. You could try return `Product` to test `[Produces("application/xml")]`.

If you want to return `XDocument`, you may consider return string directly like

```
public string Get()
{
    XDocument srcTree = new XDocument(
        new XComment("This is a comment"),
        new XElement("Root",
            new XElement("Child1", "data1"),
            new XElement("Child2", "data2"),
            new XElement("Child3", "data3"),
            new XElement("Child2", "data4"),
            new XElement("Info5", "info5"),
            new XElement("Info6", "info6"),
            new XElement("Info7", "info7"),
            new XElement("Info8", "info8")
        )
    );

    XDocument doc = new XDocument(
        new XComment("This is a comment"),
        new XElement("Root",
            from el in srcTree.Element("Root").Elements()
            where ((string)el).StartsWith("data")
            select el
        )
    );
    return doc.ToString();
}
```

Update:

The expected result is caused by the wrong XDocument creation. Try something like below:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9";
XDocument sitemap = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "yes"),
    new XElement(ns + "urlset",
        new XElement(ns + "url",
            new XElement(ns + "loc", "http://app4rental.com/business/100/r.s.-enterprises"),
            new XElement(ns + "lastmod", "2019-08-01"),
            new XElement(ns + "changefreq", "weekly"),
            new XElement(ns + "priority", "0.8")
    )));

return sitemap.ToString();
```

Comment: Yes, Its working for me but the return XML is not in proper format. I've updated my controller code please check out.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer resolved my issue according to my question. Now I'll resolve XML formatting issues.