# How to Serialize Complex C# class to XML and send it as response from .net core API?

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-core-webapi, xmlserializer

I have created an object(Complex object) in c# which I want to send a response from API in XML.
How can I set the value to complex nodes and Serialize  it in proper XML.

Below is my code..

1. C# object which I want to convert

```cs
[XmlRoot]
[Serializable]
public class Response
{
    private Response headerField;

    private Response bodyField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public Response Header
    {
        get
        {
            return this.headerField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.headerField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public Response Body
    {
        get
        {
            return this.bodyField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.bodyField = value;
        }
    }

}

public class Header
{
    public string ACCT_NUM { get; set; }
    public string NIC { get; set; }
    public string requestId { get; set; }
    public string BankId { get; set; }
}

public class Body
{
    public string STATUS { get; set; }
    public Body ERROR { get; set; }
}

public class ERROR
{
    public string ERRORCODE { get; set; }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string ERRORDESC { get; set; }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string ERRORTYPE { get; set; }

}
```

2. Serialize code by which I am setting values to fields and sending.

```cs
 var header = new Header()
            {
                ACCT_NUM= arr[0].ACCT_NUM.ToString(),
                BankId= arr[0].BankId.ToString(),
                requestId= arr[0].requestId.ToString(),
                NIC= arr[0].NIC.ToString()
            };

            var body = new Body()
            {
                STATUS = "SUCCESS"
            };

using(var stream=new MemoryStream())
{
    XmlSerializer xmlSer=new
    XmlSerializer(typeof(Response));xmlSer.Serialize(stream,new Response()
    {
        Header = header,
        Body = body
    });

    stream.Position = 0;
    using(var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        string value = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Please guide me here how can I achieve to Serialize the object in  XML and sent it as  response from API.

Comment: Check this : It will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38316358/why-wont-my-asp-net-core-web-api-controller-return-xml

Comment: Hi @ZeeCode I tried a lot but did not understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
public string SerializeToString()
    {
        var emptyNamespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces(new[] { XmlQualifiedName.Empty });
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(this.GetType());
        var settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.Indent = true;
        settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;

        using (var stream = new StringWriter())
        using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, this, emptyNamespaces);
            return stream.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Fazal Qayyun how can i access complex object mean if you see my start tag is response then header and then there is fields in header.. i need that flow to be generated in xml

Comment: Your code only provides me the below XML response.                                           
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Response xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />

Comment: I want my response like as below      <Response><Header><A1></A1><A2><A2></Header><Body><B1></B1><E1></E1></Body></Response>

Comment: @MayurWaghulde i have updated my answer i hope this will help you. Kindly try now above one.

Answer (score 0):

You can add xml serialisation support to .net core mvc. This would allow the client to request xml via setting the Accept header.

```cs
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true; // false by default
    .OutputFormatters.Insert(0, new XmlSerializerOutputFormatter());
    options.FormatterMappings.SetMediaTypeMappingForFormat("xml", MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/xml"));
});
```

Or you can match the response type based on a format argument in the request path;

```cs
        [Route("{id}.{format}"), FormatFilter]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Load(int id)
```

Comment: Hi @Jeremy Lakeman, Yes my post method accepts XML as a request and I am able to to that next challenge for me is to pass response in XML and I have created response according to me ...The above class have created I want that to be my response from API in XML. Formatter will do job but  in my case i have object  which i need to serialize in xml and pass it simply .

Answer (score 0):

controller get x-www-form-urlencoded body and send request XML or JSON (filter.JSON=true for json response body)

```
    [HttpPost("getbnprices")]
    [Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")]
    
    public ActionResult GetBnPricesXForm([FromForm] FilterListApiModel filter)
    {
        filter.UserName = filter.Login;

        try
        {
            if (filter == null)
                return BadRequest();

            var result = _leftoversSupervisor.GetBnPrices(filter).ToList();
            if (result == null) return Ok();
            var Pricelist = new BnPriceListXml<BnPriceApiModel>();
            Pricelist.AddRange(result);

            if (!filter.JSON)
            {

                var xmlOut = XmlSerializerExtension.OutXmlString(Pricelist);
                return new ContentResult
                {
                    ContentType = "text/xml; charset=WINDOWS-1251", //if necessary change charset 
                    Content = xmlOut,
                    StatusCode = 200
                };
            }
            else
            {
                return Ok(Pricelist); // response body in json
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(500, ex);
        }
    }
```

and method for serializing XML from object ( for clean result delete namespaces and change some chars for valid XML document)

```
    public static string OutXmlString<T>(T items) where T : class
    {
        var xmlString = "";
        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(items.GetType());
        var xmlSb = new StringBuilder();
        using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter, new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true }))
            {
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, items);
                xmlString = stringWriter.ToString();
            }
        }
        string strXMLPatternNamspace = @"[\s]xmlns(:\w+)?=""([^""]+)""|xsi(:\w+)?=""([^""]+)""";
        xmlString = Regex.Replace(xmlString, strXMLPatternNamspace, "");
        xmlSb.Append(xmlString);
        xmlSb.Replace("-", "&#45;");
        xmlSb.Replace(@"""", "&quot;");
        xmlSb.Replace(@"'", "&apos;");
        xmlSb.Replace(@"<?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;utf&#45;16&quot;?>", @"<? xml version = ""1.0"" encoding = ""windows-1251""?>");

        return  xmlSb.ToString();
    }
```

example output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
<Pricelist>
    <Product>
        <TypeName>Моноблоки</TypeName>
        <CategoryID>582</CategoryID>
        <ItemType>23.8&quot;</ItemType>
        <ItemCode>365425</ItemCode>
        <Artikul>XA24.HK7.I14.8.S2.N.U.075</Artikul>
        <Vendor>Expert PC</Vendor>
        <ItemName>Персональний комп`ютер&#45;моноблок Expert PC G24h (XA24.HK7.I14.8.S2.N.U.075) White</ItemName>
        <warranty>36</warranty>
        <UCGFEA>8471</UCGFEA>
        <barcode> </barcode>
        <qty>10</qty>
        <price>22265</price>
        <price_RIP>28199</price_RIP>
        <weight></weight>
        <width></width>
        <height></height>
        <depth></depth>
        <volume></volume>
    </Product>
</Pricelist>
```

maybe need configure your service

```
    public static void AddControllersWithFormatters(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
        services.AddControllers(options =>
        {
            options.Filters.Add(new ProducesAttribute("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
            options.Filters.Add(new ProducesAttribute("application/xml"));
            options.Filters.Add(new ProducesAttribute("text/xml"));
            options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;
            options.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerOutputFormatterNamespace());
            options.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerOutputFormatter(new XmlWriterSettings
            {
                Encoding = Encoding.UTF8,
                OmitXmlDeclaration = false
            }));
        }).AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
        }).AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
        //.AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters();
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).