# WEB API dot net 6 my controller returns XElement so don't need serialisation

Tags: xml, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, xelement, asp.net-core-6.0

I have an old web API that build directly XML as XElement.
I want to switch to ASP.NET core 6 web api but I want to return the same XML as before.
So I don't need serialisation I want to return directly my XElement What must I do ?

Jean

Comment: Have you tried returning the `XElement`?  What problem do you have?  If the problem is that it is getting serialized as JSON then you may need to attach an XML serializer as shown in [Why won't my ASP.Net Core Web API Controller return XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38316358) and configure to return XML as shown in [How to make ASP.NET Core return XML result?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59190580)..  Since you are returning `XElement` I believe either XmlSerializer or DataContractSerializer should work.

Comment: Can this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8373552/serialize-an-object-to-xelement-and-deserialize-it-in-memory